# How to import a field value translation in Odoo 11 by CSV?

Tags: csv, odoo, odoo-11

I am importing product templates through a CSV file. One of the columns of the file is `description_sale`, which is in English. But I was also given the `description_sale` column in other languages, to import its translations to see the right words when doing actions like printing a sale order PDF report for a customer. In this case the `descrition_sale` field should be shown in the customer's language.

To manage that, I need to import the translations of the column. I have tried creating a new CSV file to import in the `ir_translation` table. I was able to fill in every column except for the `res_id` one. The problem is that is not a `Many2one` field, but an `Integer`. So I cannot put `res_id/id` at the column header and fill the column in with the XML IDs of the product templates I am importing.

Can I perform this operation in a simple way? I am thinking about using the shell and other complex things I hope there are no necessary to do such a common task.

Comment: what do you mean by using the shell, and you have access to Odoo features or you use Odoo api? like a simple script file. and yes you right there is no easy solution you need to get all the corresponding IDs

Comment: @Elegant Odoo I mean to execute `python3 /your/odoo-bin/path --addons-path=/your/addons/paths/comma/separated shell --config=/your/config/file -d your_database_name`, to have an Odoo console, and at the end of the operations you want to perform, `self.env.cr.commit()` to make changes be persistent in the database.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you have a CSV which has two (or more) columns which should be put into `description_sale` field: the first one is the product description in English, while the other columns refer to the same field in some other language.

The easiest way to import those translations, is to do it while importing the whole CSV itself, without creating another CSV.
Let's say we have 3 CSV columns: `Sale Descr EN`, `Sale Descr DE`, `Sale Descr FR`.
All you have to do is to create your product first, then update it like this:

```
DESCR_LANG_MAP = {
    'de_DE': 'Sale Descr DE',
    'en_US': 'Sale Descr EN',
    'fr_FR': 'Sale Descr FR',
}

prod_tmpl = self.env['product.template'].create(vals)

for lang, col_name in DESCR_LANG_MAP.items():
    prod_tmpl.with_context(lang=lang).write({
        'description_sale': csvrow.get(col_name, '')
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! But, which file are you adding that code in? I was trying to avoid additional modules' development to perform the operation. In that case, I would prefer to use the shell.

Comment: You can safely create a python script, then have Odoo run it via its shell.
First of all, find the `odoo-bin` executable, and write your script in a file (e.g.: `my-script.py`).
From the odoo-bin executable directory, run this command:
`echo "exec(open('<path/to/my-script.py>').read())" | python odoo-bin shell -d <your_database> -c <path/to/your/odoo.cfg>`
(Remember to use `python3` instead of `python` according to your needs and config.)
An Odoo instance will be loaded and the content of your script will be executed. This instance will be quit as soon as the script will be over.

Comment: If I used the shell I think I'd have a simpler solution: after importing the CSV (with the sale description in English), I'd do a loop to obtain the database IDs of all the records imported (I'd obtain them with `ref` and their XML IDs), and I'd create their `ir.translation` records. Your code needs to read the CSV file and convert all data into a dictionary `vals`. Thanks anyway.